# I am getting this "Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!"

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot, however receive this error every time I try to run a youtube link.

```
Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
    at Function.getInfo (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:130:11)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:38)
    at new FFmpeg (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:44:27)
    at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:47:20)
    at VoiceConnection.play (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:71:28)
    at Object.play (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\commands\play.js:78:8)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\commands\play.js:48:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:14004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\-\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:14004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandl
ed promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14004) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I installed ffmpeg with `npm install -g ffmpeg-binaries` to try and install it globally. I also added ffmpeg to PATH, but that did not seem to work.

Anyway to fix it?

Comment: What made you think that the ffmpeg-binaries is what you need? I would recommend installing one of the dependencies listed in the Dependencies section of the readme for prism-media package https://www.npmjs.com/package/prism-media#dependencies

Comment: Also did you try to run `ffmpeg -h` to make sure system finds it?

Comment: Hey so I have the same issue and I did some digging and some experiments and my issue is 100% related to the size of the file being passed in via the url. So i can play youtube videos that are pure static images with audio like an album cover playing a song but I CANNOT play ANY music videos with audio. I saw several similar issues but still do not have an actual fix for this. I will update when i find one. Please post an answer here if you do too before me.

Answer (score 28):

try to run this `npm i ffmpeg-static`

Answer (score 4):

Are you using this method?
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play

As you didn't provide any code...

I had the same issue, that day i did two things, but i don't know which one was the fix.

- Actaullay download FFMPEG http://ffmpeg.org/download.html - put executable (ffmpeg.exe) in project directory **EDIT: Don't download source code, download
  from Get packages & executable files for your OS**
- Update node.js to newest version https://nodejs.org/en/

I'm not sure which one of the fixes it was. But now it also works without the file in directory, so I'm kinda confused

Also try requiring `ffmpeg-binaries` in the js file

Comment: Adding the exe files fixed the problem but how would I push this to heroku with github?

Comment: just push as you would normally do. Don't include .exe files in gitignore

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with playing audio stream in Discord.js even though I installed ffmpeg binaries, so here's a possible fix, atleast in windows if **ffmpeg** can't be ran alone in CMD.
I went to node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js on line 115 and there is an array for each possible directory of what to use (e.g ffmpeg), so I changed the array from

```
}, 'ffmpeg', 'avconv', './ffmpeg', './avconv'];
```

to

```
}, 'ffmpeg', 'avconv', './ffmpeg', 'C:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg', './avconv'];
```

and it worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

For add ffmpeg, go here:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME/settings

And find this:
[image: Go here]

Add this by "Add Buildpack" button:
https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

Answer (score -1):

install avconv and ffmpeg

it worked for me like this