# Why does it say error finding module when I already installed it

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ffmpeg

I am trying to code a discord music bot and this is my code:

```
const config = require('config.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-extra')
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.toLocaleLowerCase() === "elevator"){
        if(message.member.voice.channel){
            message.channel.send("Thanks to https://www.bensound.com for supplying us with this music.")
            play(message.member.voice.channel)
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send("Yo, please join a VC first.")
        }
    }
});

async function play(voiceChannel) {
    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    connection.play('elevator.mp3');
}

client.login(config.token);
```

For some reason even though I installed ffmpeg via npm install ffmpeg it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ffmpeg-extra'
```

EDIT: When I use const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg") I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
```

Comment: Try deleting your node modules and run `npm install` again.

Comment: You installed ffmpeg and you require ffmpeg-extra. Is that normal ? and why ?

Comment: Do you need a package called `ffmpeg-extra`? or are you trying to use the npm package `ffmpeg`? If the later, try changing your require statement to `const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');`

Comment: create `package.json` then install. Sometime while installing it install in root folder.

`npm init --y && npm install ffmpeg-extra`

Comment: @Jake i also dont seeffmpeg-extra module, there is one module https://www.npmjs.com/package/extra-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

I think you require the wrong package.

`ffmpeg-extra` is not a public package.

`ffmpeg` exists [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg).

`extra-ffmpeg` exists [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extra-ffmpeg).

Maybe you have to require one of those two package.

Comment: I used  extra-ffmpeg and I got this error  Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!

Comment: @MiqhtieLol check out this : https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1149 and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925319/i-am-getting-this-error-ffmpeg-avconv-not-found It's a new issue relative to your code. I think it's not relative to your primary question.
  

If you think my answer helped you for your first question you can validate it.